# Getting Safari-Style File Path

Tags: objective-c, macos, path, osx-mountain-lion

If you open Safari's Preferences and navigate to General, it has a drop-down menu next to the label 'Save downloaded files to.'  How do you get this Safari-style volume name or whatever?  I've done something like the following.  (I need to get it from a file path.)  I don't get the same.

```
- (NSString *)getVolumepath: (NSString *)path {
    NSArray *urlarray = [path componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    NSString *p = [urlarray objectAtIndex:2];
    return  p;
}
```

Apple, Inc. says that you cannot show the full path to a sandbox-protected folder that is assigned to the application.  But I want to show something like what Safari shows.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Do you mean that you can't do it if the application is sandboxed?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say was that you don't have to do all this just to get the [last component of a path](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/lastPathComponent).

Comment: Oh, okay.  I didn't know what sort of component it shows.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Following CodaFi's suggestion, it turns out to be as simple as the following.

```
- (NSString *)getlastpath: (NSString *)path {
    return  [path lastPathComponent];
}
```